# Collision Of Balls Code Isn't Working, Balls Sticking Together

Tags: python, simulation, collision

So I am trying to create a code that will correctly show the elastic collision of two balls of different masses. The code works if I give the balls equal masses but does not work for different masses. I have tried messing around with a ton of stuff but nothing seems to be working. I would love some help;

This is the formula I am trying to implement:
[https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/14d5feb68844edae9e31c9cb4a2197ee922e409c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edtor.png)

```
global w 
global h
global lst

w = 500
h = 500 
lst = [] 

def setup():
    size(w,h)
    global canvas
    canvas = createGraphics(1000,1000)
    canvas.beginDraw()
    canvas.background(255)
    canvas.endDraw()
    global ball1
    global ball2 
    ball1 = Ball(100,250,1,-.01,10,25)
    ball2 = Ball(300,250,-1,0,20,50)
    lst.append(ball1)
    lst.append(ball2)

def draw():
    background(255)
    textSize(32)
    fill(0, 102, 153);

    for y in range(0,len(last)):
        lst[y].show()
        lst[y].move()

        for z in range(0,y):
            lst[y].collide(lst[z])
        for z in range(y+1, len(last)):
            lst[y].collide(lst[z])
    





class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,dx,dy,m,r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dx = dx
        self.dy = dy
        self.m = m
        self.r = r
        self.ball_last_hit = None
    
    
def show(self):
    fill(0)
    ellipse(self.x,self.y,self.r*2,self.r*2)
    
def move(self):
    self.x += self.dx
    self.y += self.dy
    #Makes balls unable to go off of screen
    if self.x >= ( w - self.r):
        self.dx = self.dx * -1
    if self.x <=  self.r:
        self.dx = self.dx * -1
    if self.y >= ( h - self.r):
        self.dy = self.dy * -1
    if self.y <=  self.r:
        self.dy = self.dy * -1
      
def collide(self, other):
    distanceSquared = (self.x - other.x)**2 + (self.y - other.y)**2
    
    initialPositionSelf = PVector(self.x,self.y)
    initialPositionOther = PVector(other.x,other.y)
    xDiff1 = PVector.sub(initialPositionSelf, initialPositionOther)
    xDiff2 = PVector.sub(initialPositionOther, initialPositionSelf)
    
    initialVelocitySelf = PVector(self.dx,self.dy)
    initialVelocityOther = PVector(other.dx,other.dy)
    vDiff1 = PVector.sub(initialVelocitySelf, initialVelocityOther)
    vDiff2 = PVector.sub(initialVelocityOther, initialVelocitySelf)
    
    xDiffSq1 = xDiff1.magSq()
    xDiffSq2 = xDiff2.magSq()
    
    mTot = self.m + other.m
    
    c1 = (2*other.m)/mTot
    c2 = (2*self.m)/mTot
    
    Dot1 = vDiff1.dot(xDiff1)
    Dot2 = vDiff2.dot(xDiff2)
    
    bigConstant1 = (c1*Dot1)/xDiffSq1
    bigConstant2 = (c2*Dot2)/xDiffSq2
    
    V1F = PVector.sub(initialVelocitySelf, xDiff1.mult(bigConstant1))
    V2F = PVector.sub(initialVelocityOther, xDiff2.mult(bigConstant2))
    
    if (self.r + other.r)**2 >= distanceSquared:
        self.dx = V1F.x
        self.dy = V1F.y
        
        other.dx = V2F.x
        other.dy = V2F.y
```

Comment: please include a fully working example.  This will greatly increase likelihood that someone gives you a useful answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read up on what's expected of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think you get the award for funniest question title of 2021

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need calculate distance between the centers of the circles, but you calculate distance between the top left corners of the circle bounding box. try to change `self.x` and `self.y` to `self.x+self.r` and `self.y+self.r` (and same for the `other`). for the collision calculations

Comment: Just tried it and I'm getting the same problem, I think it has something to do with the mass since when the masses are equal the code works perfectly. No idea though. Thanks for the help.